# What's wrong with this "proof" that $nS^2/\sigma^2 \sim \chi^2(n)$?

Tags: probability, statistics

Suppose $X_1, \cdots, X_n$ are independent standard normal random variables. Define
$$\overline{X} = n^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i\ \text{and}\ S^2 = (n-1)^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - \overline{X})^2.$$
The Student's theorem of statistics states that $(n-1)S^2/\sigma^2 \sim \chi^2(n-1)$. What's wrong with the following "proof" that $nS^2/\sigma^2 \sim \chi^2(n)$?

I will first compute the distribution of $X_j - \overline{X}$. We have that
\begin{align*}
X_j - \overline{X} &= X_j - \frac{1}{n}(X_1 + \cdots + X_n) \\
&= \frac{n-1}{n}X_j - \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i \neq j} X_i.
\end{align*}
Observe that $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i \neq j} X_i$ is distributed $N\left(\frac{n-1}{n}\mu, \frac{n-1}{n^2}\sigma^2\right)$, and $\frac{n-1}{n}X_j$ is distributed $N\left(\frac{n-1}{n}\mu, \left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right)^2 \sigma^2\right)$. Then their difference is normal with mean $0$ and variance $\sigma^2 \left(\frac{n-1}{n^2} + \frac{(n-1)^2}{n^2}\right) = \sigma^2\frac{n-1}{n}$. Now that we've shown that the terms in the sum are distributed $N(0, (n-1)/n)$, multiply by $n/\sigma^2$ to normalize the terms:

\begin{align*}
\frac{n}{\sigma^2}S^2 &= \frac{n}{(n-1)\sigma^2}\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - \overline{X})^2 \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^n \left[\left(\frac{n}{(n-1)\sigma^2} \right)^{1/2} (X_i - \overline{X})\right]^2.
\end{align*}
Each term in the sum is $N(0,1)$, and since there are $n$ terms, the sum is distributed $\chi^2(n)$. Does what I've shown above contradict the Student's theorem?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: compute

\begin{align}
\text{Cov}\Bigg(\sqrt{\frac{n}{(n - 1)\sigma^2}}(X_1 - \bar X), \sqrt{\frac{n}{(n - 1)\sigma^2}}(X_2 - \bar X)\Bigg).
\end{align}

Comment: Oops, of course they are not independent, thank you!